# How to Buy Schladerer Kirschwasser in Frankfurt, Germany?

Tags: germany, food-and-drink, shopping, alcohol, frankfurt

I will visit Frankfurt (Germany) in this August and I want to buy two bottles of Schladerer Kirschwasser (alcohol, cherry brandy) near Frankfurt Main. Since I plan to go back to my country from Italy, I have no chance visiting the duty-free store which sells Schladerer in Frankfurt airport. Is there any store sales Schladerer Kirschwasser in Frankfurt?

Comment: You probably already know this but just in case: Kirschwasser is a common type of fruit brandy in South Germany/Switzerland/Austria/Alsace. You can find cheap ones in every supermarket and various premium brands in many wine shops, delicatessen (in the European sense) or upscale department stores. Not sure how you would track down products from a specific distillery (call them?), does it need to be Schladerer's?

Comment: Alternatively, if you are staying long enough in Germany or already have an address there, you can easily order online.

Comment: @Relaxed 
Thanks a lot for your introducing. For using in cocktail, I prefer Schladerer's Kirschwasser. I'd appreciate it if you recommend other brands. It's a pity that I can only find the pre-order service from the duty-free store in Frankfurt airport. I will keep searching the location of the supermarkets in Frankfurt and check if there is Schladerer's Kirschwasser.

Comment: @PedisonKao I don't know Schladerer so I wouldn't know what to recommend. I personally like [Etter](http://www.etter-distillerie.ch/) for cocktails because their Kirsch is somewhat more fruity with less of a bitter burning aftertaste than most others I have tried, without being sweet (it's still a cherry brandy, not a liqueur). I doubt you would find either in supermarkets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for products from a specific distillery or possibly advice on premium brandy, I don't think you would be well-served by supermarkets like Hit, Marktkauf, Real or Rewe. You need to track down a specialist shop.

Searches for “*Kirschwasser*” or “*Obstbrände*” (fruit brandy) did not yield anything useful but looking for [“*Spirituose*” on gelbeseiten.de](http://www.gelbeseiten.de/spirituose/frankfurt) returns a few promising results (I can't personally vouch for any of them).

Alternatively, you might also try a large upscale department store. I don't know Frankfurt very well so I might forget a local institution like KaDeWe in Berlin but I would try Karstadt or Galeria Kaufhof.

Following a comment by @GayotFow: There is also a permanent market called the [Kleinmarkthalle](http://www.kleinmarkthalle.de) where some merchants offer various fruit brandies.

In all cases, your odds of finding Schladerer products do not seem very high but you should at least find some other premium cherry brandy and, with a bit of luck, someone who could advise you on the best substitution. If you are feeling adventurous and since you plan to buy two bottles, you could even try two different distilleries!

Comment: +1, but honestly...  Please add Kleinmarkthalle.  That's what a native of Frankfurt (am Main) would instantly say...  All those kiosks of specialty schnapps and liquors and what-not make it an unquestioned favourite!

Comment: @Relaxed
Sincerely thank you for your assistance. With your advices, I have a clear direction to find them. I will share the good news if any one of store replying me that it is in stock there. :)

Comment: @GayotFow
Maybe I will be able to find not only Kirschwasser, but also other liquor and spices which are useful for bartender haha. Sincerely thanks!